# I can't delete specific row in my database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Following is the code I used to print the delete button for each data echoed.

```
<?php
            $sno=1;
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($datas)){
                echo('<b><tr><td>'.$sno.'</td><td>' .$row['id'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['faculty'].
                "</td><td>
                    <button onclick=deletee(); name='del_user' value='<?= $row['id']; ?>'> Delete </button><br>
                </td></tr>");
                ++$row;
                $sno++;
            }
        ?>
```

In script;

```
function deletee() {
    <?php
        $datas="";
        $sql="";
        $idd=$row['id'];
        $datas=mysqli_query($database,"SELECT*FROM data");
        if(isset($_POST['delete_user'])){
            $newrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($datas);
            if($newrow['id']==$idd)
            {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM data WHERE id='$idd' ";
                mysqli_query($database,$sql);
                header("Location: main.php");
            }
        }
    ?>
}
```

Yet I'm not able to delete a specified tuple. Whats the problem?
I'm trying to delete a row.
"After every data row is a delete button which deletes a specific row."

Comment: Define '*not able to delete*'. What error are you getting? What ID are you trying to delete? What data is at that row?

Comment: your button's onclick function cannot directly call php functions, it can only call javascript functions.. you will have to write a javascript function that makes an ajax call to your php function.

Comment: the quotes are valid, although unnessercery if its an int

Comment: you cant call a php function from javascript like that, you need the magic of AJAX

Comment: Any solutions if I don't make any script functions? I'm trying to delete a row. "After every data row is a delete button which deletes a specific row."

Answer (score 0):

A better option to your above would be to create your button as

```
<button onclick=deletee(<?=Row['id'] ?>)
```

From there your function would be

```
function deletee(int id){
   var url = "/Url/Where/PHP/is/run"
   $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    data: { id = id },
    success: function (response) {
        // Redirect to a page, or update whats displayed on the page here
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       // do your error logging / display to page here
    }
});
```

Now you just create a page to run the delete via your php and make sure the url in the ajax function points to that page, and it accepts a field called "id" (Note, this is using as a "POST", you can change to get etc. just make sure you do some checking on the data sent through.

If you don't want to use jquery at all, an alternative would be to make every lineitem a form pointing to the same url with a different value i.e.

```
//line item details Here
// where the submit button is use the code below instead
<form action="url/with/php/code" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $row['id']?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="delete">
</form>
```

Then have the php form it directs to check for post values, and redirect on success / do what it needs to do on failure

Comment: PHP , Javascript is on the page itself. And I don't ger success & error. :(

Comment: @PrabinAcharya the javascript will run on the page itself, your php page should be a separate file with its own url you can post to (you can do it in the same page, but you will need to do post checking at the top) try and separate your concerns, php code should be separate from your javascript and html (apart from displaying variables if you can) otherwise you will wind up in the land of spaghetti. You use the ajax i've provided to point to the page with the PHP delete code. Success means the code ran without error on the page you were pointing to.

Comment: @jerome if he doesn't have a jquery library, then he can instead create each line item as a form with id as a hidden input, on click of the form submit it will post the id to a page whos sole purpose is to run the php (will update code above to allow for this as well)